# Cannot connect to SQL Server Analysis Services even though it seems to be running

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssms

I just ran an "update edition" to update from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to Enterprise. I first ran the update edition process, and then separately added the Analaysis Services component. All these processes ran without reporting any errors.

When I open SQL Server Configuration Manager, I can see under "SQL Server Services" that Analysis Services is running.

However, when I start up SQL Server Management Studio and get to the "Connect to..." dialog, in the "Server Type" dropdown I don't get the option to select "Analysis Services" (all I get is "Database Engine" and "SQL Server Compact"). This means I can't actually connect to the Analysis Services server, even though it seems to be running.

Any suggestions as to what is going on, or what I need to change in order to enable Management Studio to "see" the Analysis Services server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Brian Knight might have answered this issue in serverfault.com. See the following link for more information: https://serverfault.com/questions/152904/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-analysis-services-on-windows-vista/153625#153625

Make sure you've installed Management Studio with the Full option. The basic installation option doesn't install support for Analysis Services. You can add Management Studio features by running the installer again. I hope this helps.

Comment: Great, many thanks! Making sure I had installed the Management Studio Full option was exactly what I needed to do. Now it works as expected.

Comment: Had the same issue with SQL Server 2008 Standard R2. However, option to install Full version of Management tools was grayed out. I was directed to run the "edition upgrade" wizard first. After this, SSMS full was available & installed OK.