# Cannot find analysis services in my sql server configuration manager

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas

I have installed SQL Server management studio and have been using it for a little while, but now I decided to connect to the analysis services, it has been showing me a server not running error. I went ahead to check configuration manager according to some online solutions but i cant find any installation of the analysis services.

> Cannot connect to (local).
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.
>   (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient)
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:2383 (System)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to SQL Server Analysis Services even though it seems to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266333/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-analysis-services-even-though-it-seems-to-be-runnin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don. It seems to be a service version problem. Are versions of console and service the same?
Here you can find a nice example of using SQL server Discovery report [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions/48284086#48284086)

Use the latest version of the installation disc.